# Python - Create a list of n index after enumeration

Tags: python, enumerate

```
words=["I","like","chocolate","I","like","strawberry"]

for i,l in enumerate(words,start=1):
    print(i)
```

This a simple code and what I would like to have the following output (i/o the one from the presented code):

[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

Meaning, I want a list composed of two sublists of n=3 with the indexes that came from the enumerate.

Is this possible? I believe it might be easy, but even after searching for an answer, nothing was good enough to provide me with what I need. Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you decide how many numbers to have in each sublist? Is it always 3? If so you can use the grouper function from itertools examples: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: It's just `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`. But more seriously, there is just no explanation in your question about how this output should be related to your input. Please clarify.

Comment: can you provide an example with an input and the corresponding output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a stab at it and hopefully the simple solution works for you.
Keep 2 lists one for enumerating and one for keeping the results. Keep checking length of one list and when it reaches the threshold append to results.

```
words=["I","like","chocolate","I","like","strawberry"]
l=[]
result=[]
for i,w in enumerate(words,start=1):
    l.append(i)
    if len(l) == 3:
        result.append(l)
        l = []
if l:
    result.append(l) # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I was looking for. Worked perfectly.